# how to pass parameters to template in chef?

Tags: chef-infra

I just started to study chef. These days, I'm testing the sample of templates on -- https://docs.chef.io/resources/template/

But I failed all the times ... Here's my code --

1. I created a cookbook named sample, and created a recipe named `default.rb`

```rb
file '/srv/www/htdocs/index.html' do
  content 'Hello World!'
end

include_recipe '::e'
```

2. Then I created another recipe `e.rb` --

```rb
default['authorization']['sudo']['groups'] = %w(sysadmin wheel admin)

default['authorization']['sudo']['users'] = %w(jerry greg)

template '/tmp/test.txt' do
  source 'test.txt.erb'
  mode '0440'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  variables(
    sudoers_groups: node['authorization']['sudo']['groups'],
    sudoers_users: node['authorization']['sudo']['users']
  )
end
```

3. In this cookbook's templates folder, I created a erb file -- `test.txt.erb`

```
Defaults        !lecture,tty_tickets,!fqdn
root          ALL=(ALL) ALL
<% @sudoers_users.each  do |user| -%>
<%= user %>   ALL=(ALL) <%= "NOPASSWD:" if @passwordless %>ALL
<% end -%>

%sysadmin     ALL=(ALL) <%= "NOPASSWD:" if @passwordless %>ALL

<% @sudoers_groups.each do |group| -%>

<%= group %> ALL=(ALL) <%= "NOPASSWD:" if @passwordless %>ALL
<% end -%>
```

4. Then after kick off "chef-client" , error message shows --

```
[2022-05-06T18:01:07+08:00] FATAL: NameError: undefined local variable or method `default' for cookbook: sample, recipe: e :Chef::Recipe
```

5. Since error shows can't find the variable named 'default' and in that sample -- it's using `node['authorization']['sudo']['groups']` to pass parameters to sudoers_groups, I think the e.rb maybe should be this --

```rb
node['authorization']['sudo']['groups'] = %w(sysadmin wheel admin)
node['authorization']['sudo']['users'] = %w(jerry greg)

template '/tmp/test.txt' do
  source 'test.txt.erb'
  mode '0440'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  variables(
    sudoers_groups: node['authorization']['sudo']['groups'],
    sudoers_users: node['authorization']['sudo']['users']
  )
end
```

6. But it still fails --

```
[2022-05-06T17:39:38+08:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I really messed up by this official sample. Please kind help me, Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Regards
Eisen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many places where attributes can be defined. For the purpose of this answer, we'll limit it to the recipe, and the attributes file. There are different [precedence rules](https://docs.chef.io/attribute_precedence/) for attributes.

Defining in cookbook's attributes file, such as `sample/attributes/default.rb` with the `default` precedence:

```rb
default['authorization']['sudo']['groups'] = %w(sysadmin wheel admin)
default['authorization']['sudo']['users'] = %w(jerry greg)
```

Then the recipe `sample/recipes/e.rb` and template `test.txt.erb` could be used as you described in your question.

But when we define the attributes in recipe, we need to use the syntax `node.<precedence>`, such as `node.default`:

Defined in `sample/recipes/e.rb`:

```rb
node.default['authorization']['sudo']['groups'] = %w(sysadmin wheel admin)
node.default['authorization']['sudo']['users'] = %w(jerry greg)

template '/tmp/test.txt' do
# and so on
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have not study the "Attributes" for chef yet. Thanks for your knowledge sharing.